NextJS and I18Next - change language and SSR causes hydration error
In my project I use the following packages:
"i18next": "^23.10.1",
"i18next-resources-to-backend": "^1.2.0",
"next": "14.1.2",
"react-i18next": "^14.1.0",
"react": "18.2.0",

H have to support several languages, for example 'en' and 'de'. in next-18next.config.js the followings are added:
const i18nConfig = {
  locales: ["en", "de"],
  defaultLocale: "en",
};

module.exports = i18nConfig;

in my root layout.tsx file I added the TranslationProvider like this:
export default async function RootLayout({children}: {children: React.ReactNode})
 : Promise<React.JSX.Element> {
  const { resources } = await initTranslations();
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <main>
          <TranslationsProvider resources={resources} locale={null} namespaces={null}>
              {children}
          </TranslationsProvider>
        </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

Where the initTranslation() function is looks as:
export default async function initTranslations(namespaces, locale, i18nInstance, resources) {
  locale = locale ?? "en";
  namespaces = namespaces ?? ["core", "ui"];
  i18nInstance = i18nInstance || createInstance();
  i18nInstance.use(initReactI18next);

  if (!resources) {
    i18nInstance.use(
      resourcesToBackend(
        (language, namespace) => import(`@/locales/texts/${language}${namespace}.json`),
      ),
    );
  }

  await i18nInstance.init({
    lng: locale,
    resources,
    fallbackLng: i18nConfig.defaultLocale,
    supportedLngs: i18nConfig.locales,
    defaultNS: "",
    fallbackNS: "",
    ns: namespaces,
    preload: resources ? [] : i18nConfig.locales,
  });

  return {
    i18n: i18nInstance,
    resources: i18nInstance.services.resourceStore.data,
    t: i18nInstance.t,
  };
}

And the translation provider looks as:
export default function TranslationsProvider({ children, locale, namespaces, resources }) {
  const i18n = createInstance();
  const user = useUserStore();
  locale = locale ?? user?.languageKey ?? "en";
  initTranslations(namespaces, locale, i18n, resources);
  return <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>{children}</I18nextProvider>;
}

As you can see, the user is come from a useUserStore() which is a custom hook, storing and retrieving the user data (for example the selected language code) from browser store. Therefore in server side unfortunately it returns nothing, which on SSR phase will eventually cause using the 'en' as default language.
When the user wants to switch language, I use the following code:
const { i18n } = useTranslation();
await i18n.changeLanguage(langCode); // eg. 'de'

This works like a charm, the change is immediate, the UI automatically uses the new language. BUT: when the user press F5, the NextJS re-initialize the whole system on server-side (SSR) with the default language 'en', then on client side uses the selected 'de' language - which causes hydration error because of the different translation on (for example) the navigation bar.
My question is - how to inform the SSR that I switched into 'de' and therefore use the 'de' language during SSR also! Without modificating all the pages already created?!
Another form of the question: I know that the useUserStore() should "store" the user data not on the browser storage, but somehow available on server side also - but how? Set as  a cookie? Then how to access this value during layout rendering and i18next initializing?
Thanks!
